# Installing a plugin in cordova removed All files(except index.js and index.html) from my project

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to install a cordova [plugin](https://github.com/pushandplay/cordova-plugin-apprate) using this https://github.com/pushandplay/cordova-plugin-apprate command. After successful execution of this command when I went to eclipse to make further implementation I found many of my projects js and CSS files were missing. Below is what I see on Node.js command prompt.

```
Fetching plugin "https://github.com/pushandplay/cordova-plugin-apprate.git" via git clone
Repository "https://github.com/pushandplay/cordova-plugin-apprate.git" checked out to git ref "master".
Installing "cordova-plugin-apprate" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-dialogs" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-dialogs" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-globalization" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-globalization" for android
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" already installed on android.
Cross-platform AppRate plugin for Cordova / PhoneGap
```

I am executing the command on plugins folder(D:\Test_Rate\testMobile\plugins>).I am unable to understand what's happening out there.

My environment info:

```
Cordova CLI: 7.0.0
Node Version: v6.9.4
Android version: 5.1.1
```

This is what I have tried,
1.)I downgraded cordova version to 6.5.0 and tried to install same problem.
2.)Tried to install by adding --nofetch flag after the command to fetch platforms and plugins using old fetching logic but to no avail.
Need some help!

Is anyone of you is facing the same problem? What am I doing wrong? Why the hell this is happening?

Please tell me how to add a plugin in existing cordova project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit the root www folder, not the one inside platforms/android/.

The one in platforms/android/ is a copy of the root one and in some cases the content of the root www folder is copied and the changes you made there are lost.

Comment: I have added my js and css files in www folder inside platforms/android/. where should I install the plugin? What should be the path?

Comment: No, you are installing the plugin fine, you DON'T have to add your files in platforms/android/, you have to work on the root www folder. Then a `cordova prepare android` will copy it from the root www to the platforms/android/.

Comment: Is anything in cordova has changed? Why do I need to do this? I have been adding files in platforms/android/ till now and previously also added plugins but this is the first time I am facing this kind of problem. Whats the issue?

Comment: As far as I know, it has always worked like I tell you, not sure why you didn't face the problem before and why only happens when you install that plugin and doesn't happen with others.

Comment: I somehow agree with your answer. I copied some files from my project to root www folder before adding the plugin and when i opened the editor the files which I added in root www folder were there.But I dont understand why this did not happen with earlier plugins which I installed. I tried adding another plugin but same it removed all the files.

Comment: What's the solution to this as I have entire project source files in www folder inside platforms/android/ ? How can I add the plugin?

Comment: Does this has something to do with newer versions of cordova? I think last time a plugin was installed in this project the cordova version was may be between 3.5.0 to 5.0.0

Comment: It might be possible that an older CLI version didn't run `cordova prepare` on plugin install, `cordova prepare` is what removes your files as it copies the root www content to the platforms/android www folder. You should move your files to the root folder and continue working on the root folder instead of using the one on platforms. Also, it's a good idea to stop using eclipse.

Comment: In IOS cordova app this plugin prevents app from rotating  in landscape orientation. App works only in portrait orientation.Any Ideas?

Comment: I don't see anything on the plugin code that might prevent the rotation, it must be another thing. Do you have other plugins? do you have an orientation preference on the config.xml?

Comment: Yes my application has other plugins and do not have any orientation preferences in config.xml.

Comment: Then it might be another plugin. Create a new question about it and provide your config.xml

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239418/adding-a-plugin-prevents-ios-cordova-app-from-rotation