# Adding a plugin prevents IOS cordova app from Rotation

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have IOS cordova application. When I add a [this Pugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-launch-review) in my app everything works fine except the application does not rotate in both Iphone and Ipad. Something strange. I am unable to figure out the cause. Need some help.

My environment info:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Node Version: v6.4.0
Android version: 3.7.0
```

Below is list of Plugins installed in my App,

```
at.modalog.cordova.plugin.html2pdf 1.0.0 "Html2pdf"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.1-dev "Console"
de.appplant.cordova.plugin.printer 0.7.1-dev "Printer"
org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.3 "File"
org.apache.cordova.file-transfer 0.5.0 "File Transfer"
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.6.0 "InAppBrowser"
```

Here is my config.xml code

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.Test.mobileapp2.0" version="3.5.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value=".25" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
    <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
    <preference name="GapBetweenPages" value="0" />
    <preference name="PageLength" value="0" />
    <preference name="PaginationBreakingMode" value="page" />
    <preference name="PaginationMode" value="unpaginated" />      

    <feature name="LocalStorage">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage" />
    </feature>
    <name>Test</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="mainpage.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <feature name="Printer">
        <param name="ios-package" value="APPPrinter" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="PhoneGapDropbox">
        <param name="ios-package" value="PhoneGapDropbox" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="LaunchReview">
        <param name="ios-package" value="LaunchReview" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Console">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="PhoneGapDropbox">
        <param name="ios-package" value="PhoneGapDropbox" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Html2pdf">
        <param name="ios-package" value="Html2pdf" />
    </feature>
</widget>
```

Root config File:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.Test.mobileapp2.0" version="3.5.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Test</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

Comment: can you post the root config.xml? that one seems the one on platforms/

Comment: FYI this plugin also adds cordova-plugin-device while adding launch-review-plugin.